# Issue using python-twitter

Tags: python, twitter, python-twitter

I'm using the [python-twitter API](https://github.com/bear/python-twitter) 
and whatever I pass to the below code as `user`, still returns my timeline and not the required user's. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
                      consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
                      access_token_key=ACCESS_KEY,
                      access_token_secret=ACCESS_SECRET)
user = "@stackfeed"
statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(user)
print [s.text for s in statuses]
```

When I do not pass the required fields into twitter.Api, it gives me an authentication error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `screen_name` keyword argument, e.g.:

```
statuses = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name="@gvanrossum")
```